# Jquery Validate doesn't work in MVC C#

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I'm working on a MVC App and I need to check if a user is registered, for that purpose I've created a model

```
public class Ejemplo
 {
   [Required(ErrorMessage="Favor especificar Username")]
   [DataType(DataType.Text)]
   public string usuario { get; set; }

   [Required(ErrorMessage="Favor especificar password")]
   [DataType(DataType.Password)]
   public string password { get; set; }
 }
```

my problem so far is that I need to send the info of the user in a JSON format via AJAX and I need to validate that the username and password info are specified, in order to accomplish that I' coded this:

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
            rules: {
                usuario: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 12
                },
                password: { required: true }
            },
            messages: {
                usuario: {
                    required: "must specify username --> validate !!!",
                    minlength: "not a valid Lenght --> validate !!!"
                },
                password: {
                    required: "must specify a password --> validate !!!"
                }
            },
             submitHandler:
                    $("#myform").on('submit', function () {
                        alert("have just pressed submit");
                        if ($("#myform").valid()) {
                            alert("here some code inside $.AJAX({})");
                        }
                        return false;
                    })
        })
    });
```

and this is my form(the code above and the form are in the same file: Index.cshtml)

```
<fieldset>
 <legend> Validaciones MVC </legend>
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Prueba", "Prueba", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "myform" }))
  {

     @Html.LabelFor(M => M.usuario);
     <br />
     @Html.EditorFor(M=>M.usuario)
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(M => M.usuario);
     <br />
     @Html.LabelFor(M=>M.password)
     <br />
     @Html.EditorFor(M=>M.password);
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(M=>M.password)
     <br />
     <br />

  <input type="submit" id="boton_id" name="boton_name" value="Enviar" />
                }
        </fieldset>
```

but it doesn't validate and doesn't show any message in case the username and password are empty, it only shows this alert:  alert("have just pressed submit"); but never shows the second alert:  alert("here some code inside $.AJAX({})"); this two alert are in

```
submitHandler:
                    $("#myform").on('submit', function () {
                        alert("have just pressed submit");
                        if ($("#myform").valid()) {
                            alert("here some code inside $.AJAX({})");
                        }
                        return false;
                    })
```

so, could you please help me and tell me where is my problem or what I' missing please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your JavaScript for calling `validate` is syntactically incorrect. You need to wrap the `submitHandler` code in a function:

```
submitHandler: function () { .... }
```

Next, `submitHandler` is already called when the `submit` event is triggered (and when the form is valid). You do not need to bind another event handler or check if the form is valid inside of `submitHandler`.

per the [documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#submithandler):

> Callback for **handling the actual submit when the form is valid**. Gets the form as the only argument. Replaces the default submit. The right place to submit a form via Ajax after it is validated.

The following should suffice:

```
submitHandler: function () {
    // Submit the form via AJAX.
}
```

Comment: Hello. I' just made the change and now it looks like:  submitHandler: function () {
              alert("have just pressed submit");
            }   but it still doesn't validate if the fields are empty

Comment: @PabloTobar: Are there any JavaScript errors on the page?

Comment: Hello @Andrew, No Sr, not any problem, do I have to specify the id of my form inside submitHandler: Function( here the id ) ?

Comment: @PabloTobar: Nope... that should work. Have you debugged your code to make sure the `.validate` call is being executed?

Comment: yes @Andrew, I' just did  right after read your comment and not any error

Comment: @PabloTobar: Hmm, not sure what it could be. Check out this example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/K3I17n and compare it with your code... anything different?

Comment: WT...!!! what did you do?  @Andrew it looks exactly the same but your code works just perfect for what I was looking for, the last question, what is the difference between your code and mine?

Comment: @PabloTobar: Hmm, you could try removing unobtrusive validation `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>`. It could be causing conflicts

Comment: How could I mark your comment as an asnwer? @Andrew

Comment: @PabloTobar: haha, glad that worked! Can't accept a comment, the best way to say "thanks" is to accept the answer. I'll be sure to update the answer with the info in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add supplementary information related to @AndrewWhitaker comment:

> Hmm, you could try removing unobtrusive validation . It could be
>   causing conflicts.

It's indeed an issue because jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js creates validator internally and associates it with the form. Next, when your below code is invoked:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
```

what jquery.validate.js actually does, is following:

```
validate: function( options ) {
    ...
    // check if a validator for this form was already created
    var validator = $.data(this[0], 'validator');
    if ( validator ) {
        return validator;
    }
```

As you can see, it just checks if there is a validator associated with your form. If yes, it is simply returned (your initialization settings are irrelevant in that case).

What you could do here (instead removing of jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js, unless you don't need it), is to access and change the validator settings directly, e.g.

```
var validator = $('#myForm').validate();
validator.settings.submitHandler = function(form) { ...
// etc.
```